# What does the `forall` keyword in Haskell/GHC do?

Tags: haskell, syntax, types, ghc, forall

I'm beginning to understand how the `forall` keyword is used in so-called "existential types" like this:

```
data ShowBox = forall s. Show s => SB s
```

This is only a subset, however, of how `forall` is used and I simply cannot wrap my mind around its use in things like this:

```
runST :: forall a. (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

Or explaining why these are different:

```
foo :: (forall a. a -> a) -> (Char, Bool)
bar :: forall a. ((a -> a) -> (Char, Bool))
```

Or the whole `RankNTypes` stuff...

I tend to prefer clear, jargon-free English rather than the kinds of language which are normal in academic environments.  Most of the explanations I attempt to read on this (the ones I can find through search engines) have these problems:

1. They're incomplete.  They explain one part of the use of this keyword (like "existential types") which makes me feel happy until I read code that uses it in a completely different way (like `runST`, `foo` and `bar` above).
2. They're densely packed with assumptions that I've read the latest in whatever branch of discrete math, category theory or abstract algebra is popular this week.  (If I never read the words "consult the paper *whatever* for details of implementation" again, it will be too soon.)
3. They're written in ways that frequently turn even simple concepts into tortuously twisted and fractured grammar and semantics.

So...

On to the actual question.  Can anybody completely explain the `forall` keyword in clear, plain English (or, if it exists somewhere, point to such a clear explanation which I've missed) that doesn't assume I'm a mathematician steeped in the jargon?

Comment: [Haskell wiki](http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types) seems to be pretty beginner friendly on this topic.

Comment: https://wasp-lang.dev/blog/2021/09/01/haskell-forall-tutorial is a pretty readable summary (seemingly inspired by this SO question!)

Answer (score 322, accepted):

Let's start with a code example:

```
foob :: forall a b. (b -> b) -> b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
foob postProcess onNothin onJust mval =
    postProcess val
    where
        val :: b
        val = maybe onNothin onJust mval
```

This code doesn't compile (syntax error) in plain Haskell 98. It requires an extension to support the `forall` keyword.

Basically, there are 3 **different** common uses for the `forall` keyword (or at least so it *seems*), and each has its own Haskell extension: `ScopedTypeVariables`, `RankNTypes`/`Rank2Types`, `ExistentialQuantification`.

The code above doesn't get a syntax error with either of those enabled, but only type-checks with `ScopedTypeVariables` enabled.

**Scoped Type Variables:**

Scoped type variables helps one specify types for code inside `where` clauses. It makes the `b` in `val :: b` the same one as the `b` in `foob :: forall a b. (b -> b) -> b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b`.

*A confusing point*: you may hear that when you omit the `forall` from a type it is actually still implicitly there. ([from Norman's answer: "normally these languages omit the forall from polymorphic types"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071136/what-does-the-forall-keyword-in-haskell-ghc-do/3071365#3071365)). This claim is correct, **but** it refers to the other uses of `forall`, and not to the `ScopedTypeVariables` use.

**Rank-N-Types:**

Let's start with that `mayb :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b` is equivalent to `mayb :: forall a b. b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b`, **except** for when `ScopedTypeVariables` is enabled.

This means that it works for every `a` and `b`.

Let's say you want to do something like this.

```
ghci> let putInList x = [x]
ghci> liftTup putInList (5, "Blah")
([5], ["Blah"])
```

What must be the type of this `liftTup`? It's `liftTup :: (forall x. x -> f x) -> (a, b) -> (f a, f b)`. To see why, let's try to code it:

```
ghci> let liftTup liftFunc (a, b) = (liftFunc a, liftFunc b)
ghci> liftTup (\x -> [x]) (5, "Hello")
    No instance for (Num [Char])
    ...
ghci> -- huh?
ghci> :t liftTup
liftTup :: (t -> t1) -> (t, t) -> (t1, t1)
```

"Hmm.. why does GHC infer that the tuple must contain two of the same type? Let's tell it they don't have to be"

```
-- test.hs
liftTup :: (x -> f x) -> (a, b) -> (f a, f b)
liftTup liftFunc (t, v) = (liftFunc t, liftFunc v)

ghci> :l test.hs
    Couldnt match expected type 'x' against inferred type 'b'
    ...
```

Hmm. so here GHC doesn't let us apply `liftFunc` on `v` because `v :: b` and `liftFunc` wants an `x`. We really want our function to get a function that accepts any possible `x`!

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
liftTup :: (forall x. x -> f x) -> (a, b) -> (f a, f b)
liftTup liftFunc (t, v) = (liftFunc t, liftFunc v)
```

So it's not `liftTup` that works for all `x`, it's the function that it gets that does.

**Existential Quantification:**

Let's use an example:

```
-- test.hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data EQList = forall a. EQList [a]
eqListLen :: EQList -> Int
eqListLen (EQList x) = length x

ghci> :l test.hs
ghci> eqListLen $ EQList ["Hello", "World"]
2
```

How is that different from Rank-N-Types?

```
ghci> :set -XRankNTypes
ghci> length (["Hello", "World"] :: forall a. [a])
    Couldnt match expected type 'a' against inferred type '[Char]'
    ...
```

With Rank-N-Types, `forall a` meant that your expression must fit all possible `a`s. For example:

```
ghci> length ([] :: forall a. [a])
0
```

An empty list does work as a list of any type.

So with Existential-Quantification, `forall`s in `data` definitions mean that, the value contained **can** be of **any** suitable type, not that it **must** be of **all** suitable types.

Comment: OK, I got my six hours and can now decode your answer.  :)  Between you and Norman I got exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you make `ScopedTypeVariables` seem worse than it is.  If you write the type `b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b` with this extension on it will still be exactly equivalent to `forall a b. b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b`.  However, if you want to refer to *the same* `b` (and not have it implicitly quantified) *then* you need to write the explicitly quantified version.  Otherwise, `STV` would be an extremely intrusive extension.

Comment: @nominolo: I didn't mean to demean `ScopedTypeVariables`, and I don't think that it's bad. imho it is a very helpful tool for the programming process, and especially for Haskell beginners, and I'm grateful that it exists.

Comment: This is a rather old question (and answer), but it might be worth updating it to reflect the fact that existential types can be expressed using GADTs in a way that (to me at least) makes the quantification much easier to understand.

Comment: @dfeuer: while the GADTs style of expressing the same thing is nice, it's not directly an answer to the question, and as the answer is already quite long, I'd prefer to not discuss those too and make it even longer

Comment: I personally think it's easier to explain/understand the existential notation in terms of its translation to the GADT form than on its own, but you are certainly free to think otherwise.

Comment: @dfeuer: you know what, that's a good point actually. so later today I'll try to make this edit

Answer (score 146):

> Can anybody *completely* explain the forall keyword in clear, plain English?

**No.** (Well, maybe Don Stewart can.)

Here are the barriers to a simple, clear explanation or `forall`:

- It's a quantifier.  You have a to have at least a little logic (predicate calculus) to have seen a universal or existential quantifier.  If you've never seen predicate calculus or are not comfortable with quantifiers (and I have seen students during PhD qualifying exams who are not comfortable), then for you, there's no easy explanation of `forall`.
- It's a *type* quantifier.  If you haven't seen [System F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) and gotten some practice writing polymorphic types, you're going to find `forall` confusing.  Experience with Haskell or ML is not enough, because normally these languages omit the `forall` from polymorphic types.  (In my mind, this is a language-design mistake.)
- In Haskell in particular, `forall` is used in ways that I find confusing.  (I'm not a type theorist, but my work brings me in contact with a *lot* of type theory, and I'm quite comfortable with it.)  For me, the main source of confusion is that `forall` is used to encode a type that I myself would prefer to write with `exists`.  It's justified by a tricky bit of type isomorphism involving quantifiers and arrows, and every time I want to understand it, I have to look things up and work out the isomorphism myself.

  If you are not comfortable with the idea of type isomorphism, or if you don't have any practice thinking about type isomorphisms, this use of `forall` is going to stymie you.
- While the general concept of `forall` is always the same (binding to introduce a type variable), the details of different uses can vary significantly.  Informal English is not a very good tool for explaining the variations.  To really understand what's going on, you need some mathematics.  In this case the relevant mathematics can be found in Benjamin Pierce's introductory text *Types and Programming Languages*, which is a very good book.

As for your particular examples,

- `runST` *should* make your head hurt.  Higher-rank types (forall to the left of an arrow) are rarely found in the wild.   I encourage you to read the paper that introduced `runST`: ["Lazy Functional State Threads"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1994/06/lazy-functional-state-threads.pdf).  This is a really good paper, and it will give you a much better intuition for the type of `runST` in particular and for higher-rank types in general.  The explanation take several pages, it's very well done, and I'm not going to try to condense it here.
- Consider

  ```
  foo :: (forall a. a -> a) -> (Char,Bool)
  bar :: forall a. ((a -> a) -> (Char, Bool))
  ```

  If I call `bar`, I can simply pick any type `a` that I like, and I can pass it a function from type `a` to type `a`.  For example, I can pass the function `(+1)` or the function `reverse`.  You can think of the `forall` as saying "I get to pick the type now".  (The technical word for picking the type is *instantiating*.)

  The restrictions on calling `foo` are much more stringent: the argument to `foo` *must* be a polymorphic function.  With that type, the only functions I can pass to `foo` are `id` or a function that always diverges or errors, like `undefined`.   The reason is that with `foo`, the `forall` is to the left of the arrow, so as the caller of `foo` I don't get to pick what `a` is—rather it's the *implementation* of `foo` that gets to pick what `a` is.  Because `forall` is to the left of the arrow, rather than above the arrow as in `bar`, the instantiation takes place in the body of the function rather than at the call site.

**Summary:** A *complete* explanation of the `forall` keyword requires math and can be understood only by someone who has studied the math.  Even partial explanations are hard to understand without math.  But maybe my partial, non-math explanations help a little.  Go read Launchbury and Peyton Jones on `runST`!

---

**Addendum:** Jargon "above", "below", "to the left of".  These have nothing to do with the *textual* ways types are written and everything to do with abstract-syntax trees.  In the abstract syntax, a `forall` takes the name of a type variable, and then there is a full type "below" the forall.  An arrow takes two types (argument and result type) and forms a new type (the function type).  The argument type is "to the left of" the arrow; it is the arrow's left child in the abstract-syntax tree.

Examples:

- In `forall a . [a] -> [a]`, the forall is above the arrow; what's to the left of the arrow is `[a]`.
- In

  ```
  forall n f e x . (forall e x . n e x -> f -> Fact x f) 
                -> Block n e x -> f -> Fact x f
  ```

  the type in parentheses would be called "a forall to the left of an arrow".  (I'm using types like this in an optimizer I'm working on.)

Comment: Actually I got the above/below/to the left of without having to think about it.  I'm a dullard, yes, but an **old** dullard who's had to wrestle with that stuff before.  (Writing an ASN.1 compiler among others.;)  Thanks for the addendum, though.

Comment: @JUST thanks but I'm writing for posterity.  I've run into more than one programmer who thinks that in `forall a . [a] -> [a]`, the forall is to the left of the arrow.

Comment: OK, going over your answer in detail, now, I have to thank you, Norman, from the bottom of my heart.  A lot of stuff has fallen into place with a loud click now, and the stuff that I still don't understand I at least recognize that I'm not *meant* to understand it and will just pass over `forall` in those circumstances as, effectively, line noise.  I'll look over that paper you linked to (thanks for the link as well!) and see if it's in my realm of comprehension.  Kudos.

Comment: I read left and I looked, literally, left. So it was highly unclear to me until you said "parse tree".

Comment: Thanks to the pointer to Pierce's book. It has a very clear explanation of System F. It explains why `exists` was never implemented. (It's not part of System F!) In Haskell, part of System F is made implicit, but `forall` is one of the things that can't be swept under the rug completely. It's as if they started with Hindley-Milner, which would allow `forall` to be made implicit, and then opted for a more powerful type system, confusing those of us that studied FOL's 'forall' and 'exists' and stopped there.

Comment: In the years since this answer was written, this sentence seems to have become less true: "Higher-rank types (forall to the left of an arrow) are rarely found in the wild." The trick `runST` uses to prevent unsafe usage is now reasonably common: see [`compile` in `reactive-banana`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-0.8.0.2/docs/Reactive-Banana.html), for example.

Comment: The entire `lens` ecosystem and the Van Laarhoven lenses it's based on depend heavily on rank 2 types. A `Lens s t a b` is a function that is polymorphic in a `Functor`.

Comment: @T_S_ That's exactly what happened. Originally Haskell (Haskell98) was specified with Hindley-Milner plus typeclasses (https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html) but GHC, through a succession of language extensions, has grown a more powerful type system based on System F (System FC to be precise) (https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/compiler/fc)

Comment: I would like to read more about that jargon, but googling for "forall to the left of an arrow" of the like results in this very StackOverflow answer and little more. May you please suggest other sources I can study? (Edit: one rare mention is: https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2023/winter/22300-1/notes/mutable-state/)

Answer (score 61):

My original answer:

> Can anybody completely explain the forall keyword in clear, plain English

As Norman indicates, it is very hard to give a clear, plain English explanation
of a technical term from type theory. We're all trying though.

There is only really one thing to remember about 'forall': **it binds types to
some scope**. Once you understand that, everything is fairly easy. It is the
equivalent of 'lambda' (or a form of 'let') on the type level -- Norman Ramsey
uses the notion of "left"/"above" to convey this same concept of scope in [his
excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071136/what-does-the-forall-keyword-in-haskell-ghc-do/3071365#3071365).

Most uses of 'forall' are very simple, and you can find them introduced in [the
GHC Users Manual, S7.8](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#explicit-foralls)., particularly [the excellent S7.8.5](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#universal-quantification) on nested
forms of 'forall'.

In Haskell, we usually leave off the binder for types, when the type is
universally quanitified, like so:

```
length :: forall a. [a] -> Int
```

is equivalent to:

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

That's it.

Since you can bind type variables now to some scope, you can have scopes other
than the top level ("[universally quantified](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#explicit-foralls)"), like your first example,
where the type variable is only visible within the data structure. This allows
for hidden types ("[existential types](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#existential-quantification)"). Or we can have [arbitrary
nesting](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#universal-quantification) of bindings ("rank N types").

To deeply understand type systems, you will need to learn some jargon. That's
the nature of computer science. However, simple uses, like above, should be
able to be grasped intuitively, via analogy with 'let' on the value level. A
great introduction is [Launchbury and Peyton Jones](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=178246).

Comment: technically, `length :: forall a. [a] -> Int` is not equivalent to `length :: [a] -> Int` when `ScopedTypeVariables` is enabled. When the `forall a.` is there, it affects `length`'s `where` clause (if it has one) and changes the meaning of type variables named `a` in it.

Comment: Indeed. ScopedTypeVariables complicate the story a little.

Comment: @DonStewart, may "it binds types to some scope" better phrased as "it binds type variables to some scope" in your explanation?

Answer (score 37):

Here is a quick and dirty explanation in plain terms that you're likely to be already familiar with.

The `forall` keyword is really only used in one way in Haskell. It always means the same thing when you see it.

**Universal quantification**

A *universally quantified type* is a type of the form `forall a. f a`. A value of that type can be thought of as **a function** that takes a **type** `a` as its argument and returns a **value** of type `f a`. Except that in Haskell these type arguments are passed implicitly by the type system. This "function" has to give you the same value no matter which type it receives, so the value is *polymorphic*.

For example, consider the type `forall a. [a]`. A value of that type takes another type `a` and gives you back a list of elements of that same type `a`. There is only one possible implementation, of course. It would have to give you the empty list because `a` could be absolutely any type. The empty list is the only list value that is polymorphic in its element type (since it has no elements).

Or the type `forall a. a -> a`. The caller of such a function provides both a type `a` and a value of type `a`. The implementation then has to return a value of that same type `a`. There's only one possible implementation again. It would have to return the same value that it was given.

**Existential quantification**

An *existentially quantified type* would have the form `exists a. f a`, if Haskell supported that notation. A value of that type can be thought of as **a pair** (or a "product") consisting of a type `a` and a value of type `f a`.

For example, if you have a value of type `exists a. [a]`, you have a list of elements of some type. It could be any type, but even if you don't know what it is there's a lot you could do to such a list. You could reverse it, or you could count the number of elements, or perform any other list operation that doesn't depend on the type of the elements.

OK, so wait a minute. Why does Haskell use `forall` to denote an "existential" type like the following?

```
data ShowBox = forall s. Show s => SB s
```

It can be confusing, but it's really describing the *type of the data constructor* `SB`:

```
SB :: forall s. Show s => s -> ShowBox
```

Once constructed, you can think of a value of type `ShowBox` as consisting of two things. It's a type `s` together with a value of type `s`. In other words, it's a value of an existentially quantified type. `ShowBox` could really be written as `exists s. Show s => s`, if Haskell supported that notation.

**`runST` and friends**

Given that, how are these different?

```
foo :: (forall a. a -> a) -> (Char,Bool)
bar :: forall a. ((a -> a) -> (Char, Bool))
```

Let's first take `bar`. It takes a type `a` and a function of type `a -> a`, and produces a value of type `(Char, Bool)`. We could choose `Int` as the `a` and give it a function of type `Int -> Int` for example. But `foo` is different. It requires that the implementation of `foo` be able to pass any type it wants to the function we give it. So the only function we could reasonably give it is `id`.

We should now be able to tackle the meaning of the type of `runST`:

```
runST :: forall a. (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

So `runST` has to be able to produce a value of type `a`, no matter what type we give as `a`. To do so, it uses an argument of type `forall s. ST s a` which certainly must somehow produce the `a`. What's more, it must be able to produce a value of type `a` no matter what type the implementation of `runST` decides to give as `s`.

So in effect the `runST` function is saying to you: "you can choose the type `a` as long as I can choose the type `s`."

OK, so what? The benefit is that this puts a constraint on the caller of `runST` in that the type `a` cannot involve the type `s` at all, since you don't know what type `s` is going to be. You can't pass it a value of type `ST s [s]`, for example. What that means in practice is that the implementation of `runST` can know that any value involving the type `s` is local to its own implementation, so it's free to do things it otherwise wouldn't be allowed to, like mutate them in place. The type guarantees that the mutation is local to the implementation of `runST`.

The type of `runST` is an example of a *rank-2 polymorphic type* because the type of its argument contains a `forall` quantifier. The type of `foo` above is also of rank 2. An ordinary polymorphic type, like that of `bar`, is rank-1, but it becomes rank-2 if the types of arguments are required to be polymorphic, with their own `forall` quantifier. And if a function takes rank-2 arguments then its type is rank-3, and so on. In general, a type that takes polymorphic arguments of rank `n` has rank `n + 1`.

Answer (score 34):

> They're densely packed with assumptions that I've read the latest in whatever branch of discrete math, category theory or abstract algebra is popular this week. (If I never read the words "consult the paper whatever for details of implementation" again, it will be too soon.)

Er, and what about simple first-order logic? `forall` is pretty clearly in reference to [universal quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantifier), and in that context the term [existential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantifier) makes more sense as well, though it would be less awkward if there were an `exists` keyword. Whether quantification is effectively universal or existential depends on the placement of the quantifier relative to where the variables are used on which side of a function arrow and it's all a bit confusing.

So, if that doesn't help, or if you just don't like symbolic logic, from a more functional programming-ish perspective you can think of type variables as just being (implicit) *type* parameters to the function. Functions taking type parameters in this sense are traditionally written using a capital lambda for whatever reason, which I'll write here as `/\`.

So, consider the `id` function:

```
id :: forall a. a -> a
id x = x
```

We can rewrite it as lambdas, moving the "type parameter" out of the type signature and adding inline type annotations:

```
id = /\a -> (\x -> x) :: a -> a
```

Here's the same thing done to `const`:

```
const = /\a b -> (\x y -> x) :: a -> b -> a
```

So your `bar` function might be something like this:

```
bar = /\a -> (\f -> ('t', True)) :: (a -> a) -> (Char, Bool)
```

Note that the type of the function given to `bar` as an argument depends on `bar`'s type parameter. Consider if you had something like this instead:

```
bar2 = /\a -> (\f -> (f 't', True)) :: (a -> a) -> (Char, Bool)
```

Here `bar2` is applying the function to something of type `Char`, so giving `bar2` any type parameter other than `Char` will cause a type error.

On the other hand, here's what `foo` might look like:

```
foo = (\f -> (f Char 't', f Bool True))
```

Unlike `bar`, `foo` doesn't actually take any type parameters at all! It takes a function that *itself* takes a type parameter, then applies that function to two *different* types.

So when you see a `forall` in a type signature, just think of it as a **lambda expression for type signatures**. Just like regular lambdas, the scope of `forall` extends as far to the right as possible, up to enclosing parenthesis, and just like variables bound in a regular lambda, the type variables bound by a `forall` are only in scope within the quantified expression.

---

*Post scriptum*: Perhaps you might wonder--now that we're thinking about functions taking type parameters, why can't we do something more interesting with those parameters than put them into a type signature? The answer is that we can!

A function that puts type variables together with a label and returns a new type is a *type constructor*, which you could write something like this:

```
Either = /\a b -> ...
```

But we'd need completely new notation, because the way such a type is written, like `Either a b`, is already suggestive of "apply the function `Either` to these parameters".

On the other hand, a function that sort of "pattern matches" on its type parameters, returning different values for different types, is a *method of a type class*. A slight expansion to my `/\` syntax above suggests something like this:

```
fmap = /\ f a b -> case f of
    Maybe -> (\g x -> case x of
        Just y -> Just b g y
        Nothing -> Nothing b) :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
    [] -> (\g x -> case x of
        (y:ys) -> g y : fmap [] a b g ys 
        []     -> [] b) :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Personally, I think I prefer Haskell's actual syntax...

A function that "pattern matches" its type parameters and returns an arbitrary, existing type is a *type family* or *functional dependency*--in the former case, it even already looks a great deal like a function definition.

Comment: An interesting take here.  This gives me another angle of attack on the problem that could prove fruitful in the longer term.  Thanks.

Comment: @KennyTM: Or `λ` for that matter, but GHC's unicode syntax extension [doesn't support that because λ is a letter](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1102), an unfortunate fact that would hypothetically also apply to my hypothetical big-lambda abstractions. Hence `/\ ` by analogy to `\ `. I suppose I could have just used `∀` but I was trying to avoid predicate calculus...

Answer (score 15):

> Can anybody completely explain the forall keyword in clear, plain English (or, if it exists somewhere, point to such a clear explanation which I've missed) that doesn't assume I'm a mathematician steeped in the jargon?

I am going to try and explain just the meaning and maybe the application of `forall` in the context of Haskell and its type systems.

But before you understand that I would like to direct you to a very accessible and nice talk by Runar Bjarnason titled "[Constraints Liberate, Liberties Constrain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqmsQeSzMdw)". The talk is full of examples from real world use cases as well as examples in Scala to support this statement, although it doesn't mention `forall`. I will try to explain the `forall` perspective below.

```
                CONSTRAINTS LIBERATE, LIBERTIES CONSTRAIN
```

Its very important to digest and believe this statement to proceed with the following explanation, so I urge you to watch the talk(at least parts of it).

Now a very common example, showing the expressiveness of the Haskell type system is this type signature:

`foo :: a -> a`

It is said that given this type signature, there is only one function that can satisfy this type and that is the `identity` function or what is more popularly known `id`.

In the beginning stages of me learning Haskell, I always wondered the below functions:

```
foo 5 = 6

foo True = False
```

they both satisfy the above type signature, then why do Haskell folks claim that it is `id` alone which satisfies the type signature?

That is because there is an implicit `forall` hidden in the type signature. The actual type is:

```
id :: forall a. a -> a
```

So, now let us come back to the statement: **Constraints liberate, liberties constrain**

Translating that to the type system, this statement becomes:

### A constraint at the type level, becomes a liberty at the term level

and

### A liberty at the type level, becomes a constraint at the term level

---

Now, lets look at the first statement with the `foo` function:

*A constraint at the type level..*

So putting a constraint on our type signature

```
foo :: (Num a) => a -> a
```

*becomes a liberty at the term level*
gives us the liberty or flexibility to write all of these

```
foo 5 = 6
foo 4 = 2
foo 7 = 9
...
```

Same can be observed by constraining `a` with any other typeclass etc

So now what this type signature: `foo :: (Num a) => a -> a` translates to is:

```
∃a , st a -> a, ∀a ∈ Num
```

This is known as existential quantification, which translates to *there exists* some instances of `a` for which a function when fed something of type `a` returns something of the same type, and those instances all belong to the set of Numbers.

Hence we can see adding a constraint(that `a` should belong to the set of Numbers), liberates the term level to have multiple possible implementations.

---

Now coming to the second statement and the one which actually carries the explanation of `forall`:

*A liberty at the type level, becomes a constraint at the term level*

So now let us liberate the the function at the type level:

```
foo :: forall a. a -> a
```

Now this translates to:

```
∀a , a -> a
```

which means that the implementation of this type signature should be such that it is `a -> a` for all circumstances.

So now this starts constraining us at the term level.
We can no longer write

```
foo 5 = 7
```

because this implementation would not satisfy if we put `a` as a `Bool`. `a` can be a `Char` or a `[Char]` or a custom datatype. Under all circumstances it should return something of the similar type. This liberty at the type level is what is known as Universal Quantification and the only function which can satisfy this is

```
foo a = a
```

which is commonly known as the `identity` function

---

Hence `forall` is a `liberty` at the type level, whose actual purpose is to `constrain` the term level to a particular implementation.

Answer (score 9):

The reason why there are different uses of this keyword is that it's actually used in at least two different type system extensions: higher-rank types, and existentials.

It's probably best just to read about and understand those two things separately, rather than trying to get an explanation of why 'forall' is an appropriate bit of syntax in both at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

## How is existential existential?

> With Existential-Quantification, `forall`s in `data` definitions mean
>   that, the value contained **can** be of **any** suitable type, not
>   that it **must** be of **all** suitable types.
>   -- [yachiru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3071932/4298567)

An explanation of why `forall` in `data` definitions are isomorphic to `(exists a. a)` (pseudo-Haskell) can be found in [wikibooks's "Haskell/Existentially quantified types"](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types#Explaining_the_term_existential).

The following is a brief verbatim summary:

```
data T = forall a. MkT a -- an existential datatype
MkT :: forall a. a -> T -- the type of the existential constructor
```

When pattern-matching/deconstructing `MkT x`, what is the type of `x`?

```
foo (MkT x) = ... -- -- what is the type of x?
```

`x` can be any type (as stated in the `forall`), and so it's type is:

```
x :: exists a. a -- (pseudo-Haskell)
```

Therefore, the following are isomorphic:

```
data T = forall a. MkT a -- an existential datatype
data T = MkT (exists a. a) -- (pseudo-Haskell)
```

## forall means forall

My simple interpretation of all this, is that "`forall` really means 'for all'".
An important distinction to make is the impact of `forall` on the **definition** versus function **application**.

A `forall` means the **definition** of the value or function must be polymorphic.

If the thing being defined is a polymorphic **value**, then it means that the value must be valid for all suitable `a`, which is quite restrictive.

If the thing being defined is a polymorphic **function**, then it means that the function must be valid for all suitable `a`, which isn't that restrictive because just because the function is polymorphic doesn't mean the parameter being **applied** have to be polymorphic. That is, if the function is valid for all `a`, then conversely **any** suitable `a` can be **applied** to the function. However, the type of the parameter can only be chosen once in the function definition.

If a `forall` is inside the function parameter's type (i.e., a `Rank2Type`) then it means the **applied** parameter must be **truly** polymorphic, to be  consistent with the idea of `forall` means **definition** is polymorphic. In this case, the type of the parameter can be chosen more than once in the function definition (["and is chosen by the implementation of the function", as pointed out by Norman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3071365/4298567))

Therefore, the reason why existential `data` definitions allows **any** `a` is because the data constructor is a polymorphic **function**:

```
MkT :: forall a. a -> T
```

kind of MkT :: `a -> *`

Which means any `a` may be applied to the function. As opposed to, say, a polymorphic **value**:

```
valueT :: forall a. [a]
```

kind of valueT :: `a`

Which means that the **definition** of valueT must be polymorphic. In this case, `valueT` can be defined as empty list `[]` of all types.

```
[] :: [t]
```

## Differences

Even though the meaning for `forall` is consistent in `ExistentialQuantification` and `RankNType`, existentials has a difference since the `data` constructor can be used in pattern matching. As documented in the [ghc user guide](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#idp23505120):

> When pattern matching, each pattern match introduces a new, distinct, type for each existential type variable. These types cannot be unified with any other type, nor can they escape from the scope of the pattern match.