# What does "exists" mean in Haskell type system?

Tags: haskell, exists, forall, quantifiers

I'm struggling to understand the `exists` keyword in relation to Haskell type system. As far as I know, there is no such keyword in Haskell by default, but:

- There are [extensions](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/ExistentialQuantification) which add them, in declarations like these `data Accum a = exists s. MkAccum s (a -> s -> s) (s -> a)`
- I've seen a paper about them, and (if I recall correctly) it stated that `exists` keyword is unnecessary for type system since it can be generalized by `forall`

But I can't even understand what `exists` means.

When I say, `forall a . a -> Int`, it means (in my understanding, the incorrect one, I guess) "for every (type) `a`, there is a function of a type `a -> Int`":

```
myF1 :: forall a . a -> Int
myF1 _ = 123
-- okay, that function (`a -> Int`) does exist for any `a`
-- because we have just defined it
```

When I say `exists a . a -> Int`, what can it even mean? "There is at least one type `a` for which there is a function of a type `a -> Int`"? Why one would write a statement like that? What the purpose? Semantics? Compiler behavior?

```
myF2 :: exists a . a -> Int
myF2 _ = 123
-- okay, there is at least one type `a` for which there is such function
-- because, in fact, we have just defined it for any type
-- and there is at least one type...
-- so these two lines are equivalent to the two lines above
```

Please note it's not intended to be a real code which can compile, just an example of what I'm imagining then I hear about these quantifiers.

---

P.S. I'm not exactly a total newbie in Haskell (maybe like a second grader), but my Math foundations of these things are lacking.

Comment: I'm looking forward to a great answer. Thanks for asking.

Comment: This link: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type may be of some help.

Comment: `Ctrl-F exists` - one occurrence, and not in the main text... But I'm reading it, thank you very much

Comment: @valya: yes. The Essential Haskell phd thesis linked there is perhaps worth reading too.

Comment: answers to this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071136/what-does-the-forall-keyword-in-haskell-ghc-do

Comment: Thank you for your awesome answers. I like mokus' and rampion's most, but I don't know which to choose. I'll use the answer with the most score tomorrow

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A use of existential types that I've run into is with my [code for mediating a game of Clue](https://github.com/rampion/clue).

My mediation code sort of acts like a dealer.  It doesn't care what the types of the players are - all it cares about is that all the players implement the hooks given in the `Player` typeclass.

```
class Player p m where
  -- deal them in to a particular game
  dealIn :: TotalPlayers -> PlayerPosition -> [Card] -> StateT p m ()

  -- let them know what another player does
  notify :: Event -> StateT p m ()

  -- ask them to make a suggestion
  suggest :: StateT p m (Maybe Scenario)

  -- ask them to make an accusation
  accuse :: StateT p m (Maybe Scenario)

  -- ask them to reveal a card to invalidate a suggestion
  reveal :: (PlayerPosition, Scenario) -> StateT p m Card
```

Now, the dealer could keep a list of players of type `Player p m => [p]`, but that would constrict
all the players to be of the same type.

That's overly constrictive.  What if I want to have different kinds of players, each implemented
differently, and run them against each other?

So I use `ExistentialTypes` to create a wrapper for players:

```
-- wrapper for storing a player within a given monad
data WpPlayer m = forall p. Player p m => WpPlayer p
```

Now I can easily keep a heterogenous list of players.  The dealer can still easily interact with the
players using the interface specified by the `Player` typeclass.

Consider the type of the constructor `WpPlayer`.

```
    WpPlayer :: forall p. Player p m  => p -> WpPlayer m
```

Other than the forall at the front, this is pretty standard haskell.  For all types
p that satisfy the contract `Player p m`, the constructor `WpPlayer` maps a value of type `p`
to a value of type `WpPlayer m`.

The interesting bit comes with a deconstructor:

```
    unWpPlayer (WpPlayer p) = p
```

What's the type of `unWpPlayer`?  Does this work?

```
    unWpPlayer :: forall p. Player p m => WpPlayer m -> p
```

No, not really.  A bunch of different types `p` could satisfy the `Player p m` contract
with a particular type `m`.  And we gave the `WpPlayer` constructor a particular
type p, so it should return that same type.  So we can't use `forall`.

All we can really say is that there *exists* some type p, which satisfies the `Player p m` contract
with the type `m`.

```
    unWpPlayer :: exists p. Player p m => WpPlayer m -> p
```

Comment: This is the functional way to do OOP's polymorphism.

Answer (score 15):

> When I say, forall a . a -> Int, it
>   means (in my understanding, the
>   incorrect one, I guess) "for every
>   (type) a, there is a function of a
>   type a -> Int":

Close, but not quite.  It means "for every type a, *this* function can be considered to have type a -> Int".  So `a` can be specialized to any type of the caller's choosing.

In the "exists" case, we have: "there is some (specific, but unknown) type a such that this function has the type a -> Int".  So `a` must be a specific type, but the caller doesn't know what.

Note that this means that this particular type (`exists a. a -> Int`) isn't all that interesting - there's no useful way to call that function except to pass a "bottom" value such as `undefined` or `let x = x in x`.  A more useful signature might be `exists a. Foo a => Int -> a`.  It says that the function returns a specific type `a`, but you don't get to know what type.  But you do know that it is an instance of `Foo` - so you can do something useful with it despite not knowing its "true" type.

Comment: Since exists doesn't exist in Haskell, what would be the equivalent forall notation for your second example? `exists a. Foo a => Int -> a`

Answer (score 7):

It means precisely "there exists a type `a` for which I can provide values of the following types in my constructor." Note that this is different from saying "the value of `a` is `Int` in my constructor"; in the latter case, I know what the type is, and I could use my own function that takes `Int`s as arguments to do something else to the values in the data type.

Thus, from the pragmatic perspective, existential types allow you to **hide the underlying type in a data structure**, forcing the programmer to only use the operations you have defined on it. It represents **encapsulation.**

It is for this reason that the following type isn't very useful:

```
data Useless = exists s. Useless s
```

Because there is nothing I can do to the value (not quite true; I could `seq` it); I know nothing about its type.

Comment: maybe you could elaborate a bit with not useless example? thank you very much. (your blog is awesome, by the way, teaches me a lot)

Answer (score 5):

[UHC](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/bin/view/UHC/WebHome) implements the exists keyword. Here's an example from its documentation

```
x2 :: exists a . (a, a -> Int)
x2 = (3 :: Int, id)

xapp :: (exists b . (b,b -> a)) -> a
xapp (v,f) = f v

x2app = xapp x2
```

And another:

```
mkx :: Bool -> exists a . (a, a -> Int)
mkx b = if b then x2 else ('a',ord)

y1 = mkx True -- y1 :: (C_3_225_0_0,C_3_225_0_0 -> Int)
y2 = mkx False -- y2 :: (C_3_245_0_0,C_3_245_0_0 -> Int)

mixy = let (v1,f1) = y1
            (v2,f2) = y2
       in f1 v2
```

"mixy causes a type error. However, we can use y1 and y2 perfectly well:"

```
main :: IO ()
main = do putStrLn (show (xapp y1))
          putStrLn (show (xapp y2))
```

ezyang also blogged well about this: http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/10/existential-type-curry/