# When is a generic function not generic?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, scotty

I'm working on a Haskell server using `scotty` and `persistent`. Many handlers need access to the database connection pool, so I've taken to passing the pool around throughout the app, in this sort of fashion:

```
main = do
    runNoLoggingT $ withSqlitePool ":memory:" 10 $ \pool ->
        liftIO $ scotty 7000 (app pool)

app pool = do
    get "/people" $ do
        people <- liftIO $ runSqlPool getPeople pool
        renderPeople people
    get "/foods" $ do
        food <- liftIO $ runSqlPool getFoods pool
        renderFoods food
```

where `getPeople` and `getFoods` are appropriate `persistent` database actions that return `[Person]` and `[Food]` respectively.

The pattern of calling `liftIO` and `runSqlPool` on a pool becomes tiresome after a while - wouldn't it be great if I could refactor them into a single function, like Yesod's `runDB`, which would just take the query and return the appropriate type. My attempt at writing something like this is:

```
runDB' :: (MonadIO m) => ConnectionPool -> SqlPersistT IO a -> m a
runDB' pool q = liftIO $ runSqlPool q pool
```

Now, I can write this:

```
main = do
    runNoLoggingT $ withSqlitePool ":memory:" 10 $ \pool ->
        liftIO $ scotty 7000 $ app (runDB' pool)

app runDB = do
    get "/people" $ do
        people <- runDB getPeople
        renderPeople people
    get "/foods" $ do
        food <- runDB getFoods
        renderFoods food
```

Except that GHC complains:

```
Couldn't match type `Food' with `Person'
Expected type: persistent-2.1.1.4:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.SqlPersistT
                 IO
                 [persistent-2.1.1.4:Database.Persist.Class.PersistEntity.Entity
                    Person]
  Actual type: persistent-2.1.1.4:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.SqlPersistT
                 IO
                 [persistent-2.1.1.4:Database.Persist.Class.PersistEntity.Entity
                    Food]
In the first argument of `runDB', namely `getFoods'
```

It seems like GHC is saying that in fact the type of `runDB` becomes specialised somehow. But then how are functions like `runSqlPool` defined? Its type signature looks similar to mine:

```
runSqlPool :: MonadBaseControl IO m => SqlPersistT m a -> Pool Connection -> m a
```

but it can be used with database queries that return many different types, as I was doing originally. I think there's something fundamental I'm misunderstanding about types here, but I have no idea how to find out what it is! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

at Yuras' suggestion, I've added this:

```
type DBRunner m a = (MonadIO m) => SqlPersistT IO a -> m a
runDB' :: ConnectionPool -> DBRunner m a
app :: forall a. DBRunner ActionM a -> ScottyM ()
```

which required `-XRankNTypes` for the typedef. However, the compiler error is still identical.

**EDIT:**

Victory to the commentors. This allows the code to compile:

```
app :: (forall a. DBRunner ActionM a) -> ScottyM ()
```

For which I'm grateful, but still mystified!

The code is currently looking like [this](https://github.com/coursestitch/coursestitch-api/blob/dcf7bbb43f312b717f0e3170551ab88ab062fa43/src/Model/RunDB.hs) and [this](https://github.com/coursestitch/coursestitch-api/blob/dcf7bbb43f312b717f0e3170551ab88ab062fa43/src/Handlers/User.hs#L15-L18).

Comment: Try to add type signature to `app` with explicit `forall` and most likely you'd see what is wrong.

Comment: @Yuras I think part of this problem is that I currently have a very poor understanding of explicit `forall`, but I shall endeavor to do so.

Comment: I guess it should be `app :: (forall a. DBRunner ActionM a) -> ScottyM ()`.

Comment: @TomEllis should I have any particular extension enabled for that? It still gives me the same error.

EDIT: okay, apologies - I had my handlers in separate functions. After adding type signatures there, and enabling more extensions (`RankNTypes` and `FlexibleContexts`) as required I'm starting to see new errors. Will report back.

Comment: Can you post your complete code?  I'd like to try things out but I don't want to guess what your imports are, etc..

Comment: @TomEllis I'm working on [this](https://github.com/coursestitch/coursestitch-api/blob/master/src/Main.hs#L21-L33), but the `runDB` stuff hasn't been pushed because obviously it isn't working :P. I can try to make a minimal example if you'd like.

Comment: @TomEllis it appears to be working now! I'll edit my question with current code. I'm still fairly mystified.

Comment: I would also suggest getting rid of the `type` and just using `app :: MonadIO m => (forall a. SqlPersistT IO a -> m a) -> ScottyM ()`.  I don't think the constraint has to be inside the `forall`.

Comment: @TomEllis I prefer having some sort of typedef to keep things brief and readable, especially since it will appear in the type of every handler (of which there are many :P). I'm going to see if I can stick the `forall` in the typedef too...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071136/what-does-the-forall-keyword-in-haskell-ghc-do? But to keep things in place: your first `runDB` call in `app` set the type variable `a` in `DBRunner m a` to `Entity People`. Therefore, the type checker assumes `runDB :: DBRunner ActionM (Entity People)`. However, your second use of `runDB` implies `runDB :: DBRunner ActionM (Entity Food)`! Oh noez! You have to tell GHC that `runDB` should take _any a_. And that's done with `(forall a . DBRunner ActionM a) ->`. Note the parentheses, the `forall` may not float out.

Comment: @Zeta that question looks very familiar from back when I was reading about `forall` in connection with `ST`. Seems it didn't sink in - but I'm still confused why `runDB` needs `forall` but `runSqlPool` doesn't.

Comment: Because `runSqlPool` comes from the top level.  If you try to pass it in as an argument you will experience the same problem.  Alternatively if you write `runDB = runDB' pool` and `app` both inside a `where` clause in the body of the `main` then you will not need `Rank2Types`.

Comment: "SQlite"? :( That should be either "Sqlite" or "SQLite".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> It seems like GHC is saying that in fact the type of runDB becomes specialised somehow.

Your guess is right.  Your original type was `app :: (MonadIO m) => (SqlPersistT IO a -> m a) -> ScottyM ()`.  This means that your `runDB` argument of type `SqlPersistT IO a -> m a` can be used at any *one* type `a`.  However, the body of `app` wants to use the `runDB` argument at two different types (`Person` and `Food`) so instead we need to pass an argument that can work for any number of different types in the body.  Thus `app` needs the type

```
app :: MonadIO m => (forall a. SqlPersistT IO a -> m a) -> ScottyM ()
```

(I would suggest keeping the `MonadIO` constraint outside the `forall` but you can also put it inside.)

*EDIT:*

What's going on behind the scenes is the following:

`(F a -> G a) -> X` means `forall a. (F a -> G a) -> X`, which means `/\a -> (F a -> G a) -> X`.  `/\` is the type-level lambda.  That is, the caller gets to pass in a single type `a` and a function of type `F a -> G a` for that *particular* choice of `a`.

`(forall a. F a -> G a) -> X` means `(/\a -> F a -> G a) -> X` and the caller has to pass in a function which the *callee* can specialise to *many* choices of `a`.

Comment: But how does that interact with the intuitive way that having a generic function can act on multiple types? Why can `runSqlPool` return different types? Is there a `forall` somewhere in `persistent`'s bowels that I just can't see?

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster: Nah. `runSqlPool` works for the same reason `f = head ["Hi"] ++ (show $ head [1..5])` works. However, if you were to use `runSqlPool` as a parameter in order to get different `a`, you would encounter the same issue - the `a` gets fixed at the first encounter.

Comment: @Zeta I see, so passing it as a parameter fixes its type. That makes sense, and I _have_ to pass `runDB` because it relies on a pool that is constructed at runtime. I could not define `runDB` (with no `'`) as a library function, only `runDB'`. That's the difference with `runSqlPool`, I guess.

Answer (score 7):

Lets play the game:

```
Prelude> let f str = (read str, read str)
Prelude> f "1" :: (Int, Float)
(1,1.0)
```

Works as expected.

```
Prelude> let f str = (read1 str, read1 str) where read1 = read
Prelude> f "1" :: (Int, Float)
(1,1.0)
```

Works too.

```
Prelude> let f read1 str = (read1 str, read1 str)
Prelude> f read "1" :: (Int, Float)

<interactive>:21:1:
    Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Float’
    Expected type: (Int, Float)
      Actual type: (Int, Int)
    In the expression: f read "1" :: (Int, Float)
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = f read "1" :: (Int, Float)
```

But this doesn't. What the difference?

The last `f` has the next type:

```
Prelude> :t f
f :: (t1 -> t) -> t1 -> (t, t)
```

So it doesn't work for clear reason, both elements of the tuple should have the same type.

The fix is like that:

```
Prelude> :set -XRankNTypes 
Prelude> let f read1 str = (read1 str, read1 str); f :: (Read a1, Read a2) => (forall a . Read a => str -> a) -> str -> (a1, a2)
Prelude> f read "1" :: (Int, Float)
(1,1.0)
```

Unlikely I can come with good explanation of `RankNTypes`, so I'd not even try. There is enough resources in web.

Comment: Thanks, this is the sort of logic I'm trying to go through in my head. I'll look up `RankNTypes` to see if I can make sense of it.

Answer (score 6):

To really answer the title question that apparently continues to mystify you: Haskell always chooses the most generic rank-1 type for a function, when you don't supply an explicit signature. So for `app` in the expression `app (runDB' pool)`, GHC would attempt to have type

```
app :: DBRunner ActionM a -> ScottyM ()
```

which is in fact shorthand for

```
app :: forall a. ( DBRunner ActionM a -> ScottyM () )
```

This is rank-1 polymorphic, because all type variables are introduced outside of the signature (there is no quantification going on in the signature itself; the argument `DBRunner ActionM a` is in fact monomorphic since `a` is fixed at that point). Actually, it is the most generic type possible: it can work with a polymorphic argument like `(runDB' pool)`, but would also be ok with monomorphic arguments.

But it turns out the implementation of `app` can't offer that generality: it *needs* a polymorphic action, otherwise it can't feed two different types of `a` values to that action. Therefore you need to manually request the more specific type

```
app :: (forall a. DBRunner ActionM a) -> ScottyM ()
```

which is rank-2, because it has a signature which contains a rank-1 polymorphic argument. GHC can't really know this is the type you want – there's no well defined “most general possible rank-n type” for an expression, since you can always push in extra quantifiers. So you must manually specify the rank-2 type.

Comment: This, combined with Tom Ellis's explanation of `forall` as introducing a type-level lambda, has really helped me. Thanks for going to the trouble!