# Specify nested type variable constraints are of same instance in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

The following which uses `FooA` explicitly as the type in `(#)` and in `queryP` compiles as expected:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Foo where

class Foo a where

newtype FooParser a = FooParser { (#) :: FooA -> (a, FooA) }

queryP :: (FooA -> a) -> FooParser a
queryP f = FooParser $ \(b :: FooA) -> (f b, b)

data FooA = FooA Int
instance Foo FooA where
```

But when I try to define `FooParser` and `queryP` using the typeclass `Foo` like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Foo where

class Foo a where

newtype FooParser a = FooParser { (#) :: Foo b => b -> (a, b) }

queryP :: Foo b => (b -> a) -> FooParser a
queryP f = FooParser $ \(b :: Foo b => b) -> (f b, b)
```

I get a could-not-deduce error:

```
Foo.hs:11:52:
    Could not deduce (b ~ b1)
    from the context (Foo b)
      bound by the type signature for
                 queryP :: Foo b => (b -> a) -> FooParser a
      at Foo.hs:10:11-42
    or from (Foo b1)
      bound by a type expected by the context: Foo b1 => b1 -> (a, b1)
      at Foo.hs:11:12-53
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for queryP :: Foo b => (b -> a) -> FooParser a
          at Foo.hs:10:11
      ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           a type expected by the context: Foo b1 => b1 -> (a, b1)
           at Foo.hs:11:12
    Relevant bindings include
      b :: Foo b => b (bound at Foo.hs:11:26)
      f :: b -> a (bound at Foo.hs:11:8)
      queryP :: (b -> a) -> FooParser a (bound at Foo.hs:11:1)
    In the expression: b
    In the expression: (f b, b)
```

How can I specify that the `b` in the lambda function in `queryP` is of the same instance of the typeclass `Foo` as in the first parameter of `f`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the type definition

```
newtype FooParser a = FooParser { (#) :: Foo b => b -> (a, b) }
```

the type variable `b` is bound universially in a higher-rank type; i.e. the type of the newly introduced selector function `(#)` is

```
*Foo> :t (#)
(#) :: Foo b => FooParser a -> b -> (a, b)
```

But that means when you construct a `FooParser a`, the function you pass to the constructor must be typed at `b -> (a, b)` for **any** choice of `b` (as long as `Foo b` holds):

```
*Foo> :t FooParser
FooParser :: (forall b. Foo b => b -> (a, b)) -> FooParser a
```

However, in `queryP` you are given a function of type `b -> a` for **some** choice of `b` (the `b` is chosen by the caller, with the only restriction that `Foo b` will hold).

So if I set `b ~ b1` and call `queryP`, that means I am passing you a function of type `f :: b1 -> a`. You then have to return to me a function of type `forall b. (Foo b) => b -> (a, b)` (wrapped in the constructor `FooParser`).

You can't just use `f` for this purpose, as for any choice of `b` other than `b1` (e.g. `b ~ b2`) it will not be of the right type.

In its present form, you can basically only use functions from the `Foo` class and parametrically sufficiently polymorphic functions to construct your `forall b. (Foo b) => b -> (a, b)` function. Depending on what you are trying to do, you can either

- Change `queryP` so that it takes a polymorphic function:

```
queryP :: (forall b. Foo b => (b -> a)) -> FooParser a
queryP f = FooParser $ \b -> (f b, b)
```

- Change `FooParser` so that `b` is existentially bound:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data FooParser a = forall b. Foo b => FooParser { (#) :: b -> (a, b) }
```

Note that these two changes mean (and imply) very different things.

Comment: Changing `queryP` appears to be what I needed. So putting the `forall` explicitly on the type of the function `f` is what makes it polymorphic? Is this basically the same situation as the Rank-N-Types section of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3071932/1542000 ?

Comment: Yes. You could say it is a simple matter of parenthesization: `forall a. a -> Bool` means `forall a. (a -> Bool)` as opposed to `(forall a. a) -> Bool` which requires explciit parentheses (and turning on higher-rank types, of course).