# Confusing about Haskell type inference

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, type-inference

I have just started learning Haskell. As Haskell is static typed and has polymorphic type inference, the type of the identity function is

```
id :: a -> a
```

suggesting id can take any type as its parameter and return itself. It works fine when I try:

```
a = (id 1, id True)
```

I just suppose that at compile time, the first id is Num a :: a -> a, and the second id is Bool -> Bool. When I try the following code, it gives an error:

```
foo f a b = (f a, f b)
result = foo id 1 True
```

It shows the type of a must be the same type of b, since it works fine with

```
result = foo id 1 2
```

But is that true that the type of id's parameter can be polymorphic, so that a and b can be different type?

Comment: is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction what you want?

Comment: @haoformayor No, this is about `forall`, not the monomorphism restriction, I think. The inferred type for `foo` would have to be `(forall a . a -> a) -> a -> b -> (a, b)`, but AFAIK haskell never infers types with a `forall` (called rank-2 types, I think?), even with the monomorphism restriction disabled.

Comment: ah, that's the answer. ghc infers the rank-1 type `forall a b. (a -> b) -> a -> a -> (b, b)`, but you really want `(forall a. a -> a) -> a -> b -> (a, b)`.

Comment: I don't really have time to flesh this out into an answer, but feel free to do so if you've got time, @haoformayor.

Answer (score 11):

All right, this is a weird spooky corner of Haskell's type system. The problem here is that there are two ways to type inference your function `foo`.

```
-- rank 1
foo :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> a -> a -> (b, b)
foo f a b = (f a, f b)

-- rank 2
foo' :: (forall a. a -> a) -> a -> b -> (a, b)
foo' f a b = (f a, f b)
```

The second type is the one you want, but the first type is the one you're getting. The second type, as amalloy pointed out, is a rank-2 type (we're going to ignore what the two means but read the introduction in ["Practical type inference for arbitrary-rank types"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/higher-rank/putting.pdf) if you want a good explanation of ranks – don't be put off by the academic nature of the PDF file as the beginning is accessibly and clearly written).

We'll defer the definition of higher-ranked types for now and just say that the problem is that GHC is unable to infer the rank-2 type. Quote the paper:

> Complete type inference is known to be undecidable for higher-rank (impredicative) type systems, but in practice programmers are more than willing to add type annotations to guide the type inference engine, and to document their code....
>
> Kfoury and Wells show that typeability is decidable for rank ≤ 2, and undecidable for all ranks ≥ 3 (Kfoury & Wells, 1994). For the rank-2 fragment, the same paper gives a type inference algorithm. This inference algorithm is somewhat subtle, does not interact well with user-supplied type annotations, and has not, to our knowledge, been implemented in a production compiler.

Undecidable means there can be no algorithm that always leads to a correct yes-or-no decision. So there you have it: impossible to infer a rank-3-or-higher type, and it's too gosh-darn-hard to infer the rank-2 type.

Now, back to rank 2. The `(forall a. a -> a)` is what makes it rank-2. [There's already an excellent Stack Overflow question about what the `forall` keyword means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071136/what-does-the-forall-keyword-in-haskell-ghc-do) so I'll refer you to that, but basically it means you're able to call `f a` and `f b` in the expression `(f a, f b)` while **having `a` and `b` be different types**, which is what you wanted in the first place, before all this hot mess.

One last thing: The reason you don't normally see `forall`s in GHCi is that any `forall`s on the very outer scope are left off. So `forall a b. (a -> b) -> a -> a -> (b, b)` is equivalent to `(a -> b) -> a -> a -> (b, b)`.

Overall this is a pain point of the language that's poorly explained.

(Hat tip to @amalloy in the comments.)

Comment: It's worth noting that neither of these two types is more general than the other. Each can be used in ways that the other can't. So `foo f a b = (f a, f b)` taken in isolation is ambiguous about what function is actually being defined; at the moment that ambiguity is resolved by taking the interpretation with a rank-1 type. In a hypothetical world where GHC had perfect rank-2 inference and no historical baggage preferring the rank-1 interpretation, you'd likely be required to add something that pins down the choice, as that's not the kind of thing we'd like a compiler to choose for you.

Comment: As an aside, the type `forall a. a -> a` is inhabited by precisely one non-bottom value (`id`) so `foo'` is essentially isomorphic to `(,)`.