# Why don't these types unify when using type constraints and a typeclass instance?

Tags: purescript

So, I am attempting to develop a function that expects a polymorphic function.

I start with and create a class `Foo`, to represent the constrained type argument in the `example` function.

```
module Test
where

class Foo a
```

Along with a random type for this example...

```
newtype Bar = Bar Int
```

In order to pass `Bar` to anything that has a `Foo` constraint, it needs to have a typeclass, so I do so:

```
instance fooBar :: Foo Bar
```

Everything should be perfectly fine, however, this doesn't work, psc doesn't think the types unify and I don't know why:

```
example :: forall a. (Foo a) => (a -> Int) -> Int
example a = a (Bar 42)
```

Error as follows:

```
Error found:
in module Test
at /Users/arahael/dev/foreign/test.purs line 11, column 16 - line 11, column 22

  Could not match type

    Bar

  with type

    a0


while checking that type Bar
  is at least as general as type a0
while checking that expression Bar 42
  has type a0
in value declaration example

where a0 is a rigid type variable
        bound at line 11, column 1 - line 11, column 22

See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/TypesDoNotUnify.md for more information,
or to contribute content related to this error.
```

Comment: As a clarification, I'm aware that `example :: (forall a. (Foo a) => a -> Int) -> Int` just magically works. But I don't understand why.  If scoping was significant, then that implies that my first example in the question was really a `example :: forall b. (Foo b) => (a -> Int) -> Int`, which certainly shouldn't compile in purescript.

Comment: After discussing with coworkers, it appears that purescript effectively implements the haskell extension 'rank-n-types', and as such, https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-18-rank-n-types.html is a fantastic explanation.  Not sure how to best summarize this for stackoverflow, though.

Answer (score 1):

Compare

```
(1) example :: (forall a. (Foo a) => a -> Int) -> Int
```

with

```
(2) example :: forall a. (Foo a) => (a -> Int) -> Int
```

The latter essentially places responsibility on you, the caller, to supply as the argument to `example` a function (your choice!) w/ the signature `a -> Int` (such that there is a `Foo` instance for `a`).

The former, on the other hand, says that you, the caller, don't actually get to pick what this function `a -> Int` is. Rather, as Norman Ramsey has explained in a Haskell-related stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3071365/1667161), when the `forall` is "to the left" of the arrow (rather than "above the arrow") the *implementation* decides what function to supply. The signature in `(2)` is saying any function `a -> Int` will do as the argument to `example` (so long as there is a `Foo` intance for `a`).

If `(1)` just "magically" works, then, it's because the function that unwraps the newtype `Bar` is being selected by the compiler as perfectly satisfactory, and passed as the argument to `example` in case `(1)`. After all, the signature of `(1)` suggests that `example` should return the same `Int` values no matter what function `a -> Int` is given (so long as there is a `Foo` instance for `a`). In case `(2)`, the `Int` values returned by `example` may very well differ depending upon the specific function `a -> Int` supplied. The compiler cannot grab any such function that it knows satisfies the type at random. It cannot guess the type of `a` or `a -> Int` that you, the caller, actually have in mind.

Comment: What does my head in, is that in *both* cases, it is the caller that provides the function argument.  In both cases 1, and 2, the caller has to provide, as the first argument, a function.  Surely, my head rationalises, a Foo instance for `a` must exist in either case, so surely, they should be equivalent.

Comment: Yes but what are the constraints on this function that you can provide? In one case, you can provide any function from a to Int such that there is a Foo instance for a. In the other, the compiler knows a priori that you can only provide a function that doesnt actually use any knowledge about a except that it has a Foo instance.

Comment: What's the difference between those two cases?  Given a pure function, which takes an `a`, and returns an `Int` making use of the `Foo` instance. It certainly can't inspect the value except via the type instance, can't it? (So, what use would any "knowledge" of the type give the compiler, except, ostensibly, for optimisation purposes...)

Comment: I've added another question here, which might be the same issue I am facing here, but I don't understand it. It might shed some light as to why I am finding it confusing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817554/purescript-error-cant-match-equivalent-types

Comment: When you write (1) you promising there exists a fn that gets an Int from an a for all types a that have Foo instances. In case two, youre making no such promise that this fn exists for all a w Foo instances. What is confusing is that the forall when it is left of the arrow instead of above the arrow makes an existential promise. So the big difference bt (1) and (2) is that in (1) youre promising that such a fn exists for all as that have Foo instances, and in (2) you made no such promise. The compiler figured out in 1 that a must be Bar, bc only Bar has a Foo instance.